# Probability that you picked at least $2$ correct out of $8$, whereby the $8$ are again a sample out of $11$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

The question goes like this: You write a test and have $11$ topics in total. In the test, the teacher picks $8$ out of the $11$ topics. For each number of topics you study, what are the probabilities that you studied for at least two topics asked for in the test.
I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but am stuck since a while now.

Comment: Break the problem into 3 categories. Firstly when u studied 0 or 1. Then 2,3 or 4 then 5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one thing to note is that the question indicates is without replacement, so when a teacher picks a topic she won't choose it again, this is usually a good hint for you to think about the hypergeometric distribution as that is the only probability distribution with no replacement.

In general, the distribution takes the following form:

$\frac{{K \choose k} {N-K \choose n-k}}{N \choose n} $

Where:

$N$ is the population size,
$K$ is the number of success states in the population,
$n$ is the number of draws (i.e. quantity drawn in each trial),
$k$ is the number of observed successes

Now getting to your question:

Since it is worded as "what are the probabilities" I am assuming they want each probability separate, even though that is unusual in such exercises, we have the following, the probability that you studied exactly two correct topics is (note that I am assuming that :

When you study $0$ and $1$ topic then the probability of having $2$ correct is $0$, I guess that is pretty trivial.

Otherwise, the probability of getting $2$ topics correct when you studied for $k$ topics is:

$\frac{{8 \choose 2} {3 \choose k-2}}{11 \choose 8} $

Otherwise, the probability of getting $3$ topics correct when you studied for $k$ topics is, obviously this is $0$ when $k<3$ but otherwise it is:

$\frac{{8 \choose 3} {3 \choose k-3}}{11 \choose 8} $

Can you continue?

Comment: That is exactly the formula I was looking for. I would continue and to derive the distribution calculate the probability to have 2 or more successes for each number of topics I could study, i.e. by calculating the area under the density function for each value of n?